# Why aren't my Python custom math-overload class methods working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, math

Lately, I've been prototyping a lot of C algorithms in Python. In order to help me make the most accurate models, I tried to create a custom data-type that I could use for seamlessly mixing fixed-width integers (uint8_t and friends) with standard Python math.

Towards that end, I wrote a little custom class that provides modulo-wrapped math and logic functions (to ensure that adding '1' to an 255 will return a value of 0 on an 8-bit variable).

Everything seemed to go smoothly, except that my custom math functions don't seem to get called by the interpreter!
Using the code below:

```
class MockUint(object):
    @staticmethod
    def __math__(op1, op2, name, width = 128):
        if type(op1) is MockUint:
            width = op1._width
            op1 = int(op1)

        if type(op2) is MockUint:
            width = op2._width if (op2._width > width) else width
            op2 = int(op2)

        mask = 2**width - 1
        result = int.__dict__[name](op1, op2) & mask
        return MockUint(result, width)

    def __init__(self, value=0, width=64):
        self._width = width
        self._value = value

        math_funcs = ['__add__', '__sub__', '__mul__', '__floordiv__',
                      '__mod__', '__divmod__', '__pow__', '__lshift__',
                      '__rshift__', '__and__', '__xor__', '__or__']

        for func in math_funcs:
            setattr(self, func, lambda x, y: self.__math__(x, y, func))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%d" % self._value

    def __int__(self):
        return self._value
```

I get the following results:

```
> test = MockUint(0, 8)
> test + 4
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MockUint' and 'int'
```

If I manually declare all of the functions with a pattern like,

```
def __add__(self, op):
    return self.__math__(self, op, '__add__')
```

everything seems to work as shown below:

```
> test = MockUint(0, 8)
> test + 4
4
```

I really don't want to clutter up the code with 12 identical methods if I can avoid it. How can I make the interpreter correctly detect that `__add__` and friends were created during `__init__()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) magic methods must be defined on the class, not the instance.

You have two options to solve your problem:

**1. use old-style classes**

In old-style classes (it's not like i recommend to use them) you can define magic methods on the instance and they will work. You only have to change the `lambda` function, because they are only passed one parameter (`self` is implicit here)

```
class Int:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = ...
        setattr(self, "__add__", lambda other: self.value + other)
```

**2. define the methods on the class**

```
class Int(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = ...

    @classmethod
    def static_init(cls):
        setattr(cls, "__add__", lambda self, other: self.value + other)

Int.static_init()
```

To avoid that extra call to `static_init` you can create a meta class and add the magic methods in its `__init__()`

**2b. with metaclass**

```
class IntMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args):
        setattr(cls, "__add__", lambda self, other: self.value + other)

class Int(object):
    __metaclass__ = IntMeta
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```